# Alguien sabe por que no reconoce la clase BST a la hora de compilar?

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

Aquí esta el codigo de la clase main y la clase BST[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error de compilacion que me aparece, alguien sabe que pasa?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Kevin Gutierrez. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Cambia las **imagenes por texto**, ya que es más legible, se puede copiar, y usuarios que no pueden ver las imagenes pueden leer la pregunta. Para formatear el codigo puedes pulsar `ctrl + k` o el icono `{}`. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias incorrecciones ahí:

> **1º**. La carpeta de tu proyecto es `ArbolesBinarios`, un paquete se emplea para almacenar dentro de la carpeta del proyecto, un conjunto de clases que conservan alguna relación. Hasta el momento, cuando compilas tu programa, va a la carpeta de proyecto, de ahí busca el *paquete* (*carpeta* a nivel físico) `ArbolesBinarios` y realmente no está. Porque `ArbolesBinarios` es la carpeta del proyecto, no la del paquete.
>
> **2º**. Para compilar, situados en el directorio de nuestro proyecto, debemos compilar así:
>
> ```
>   javac fuente1.java paquete\fuente2.java paquete\subpaquete\fuente3.java
> ```
>
> es decir, debemos compilar desde el directorio de nuestro proyecto y debemos poner, si hace falta, los path para llegar desde ahí a los fuentes. Esto generará los ficheros `fuente1.class`, `paquete\fuente2.class` y `paquete\subpaquete\fuente3.class`

Si no tienes muchos conocimientos sobre Java, es aconsejable que no compiles desde la consola y lo hagas a través de un IDE. Ya que precisa de altos conocimientos sobre cómo el compilador va a dejar las ficheros `.class` resultantes y necesitarás saber como dejar la estructura de carpetas y paquetes de manera ordenada.

Lo mismo sucede con el *debugger* que Java incorpora.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que cuando se utiliza la estructura de `package` la forma de compilacion/ejecucion cambia sustancialmente, un poco nada mas.
La `JVM` necesita saber cual es ese paquete donde se encuentran los archivos de `bytecode` (clases compiladas) y también donde andan los de código fuente `src`.

En este caso en especial no deberías tener problemas escribiendo la compilación así:

```
$ javac -d ~/Desktop/Examples ~/Desktop/Examples/*/*.java
```

y la ejecución de esta forma:

```
$ java ArbolesBinarios/Main
```

Todo lo anterior **sin importar el directorio donde estés**, ejecutará desde cualquier ubicación.